# Brunch create unusable SCSS sourceMaps

Tags: sass, brunch

I’m a new user of Brunch too and I don’t understand a simple thing:

- why `SCSS` sourMaps generated by Brunch show in browsers useless informations as they refers to a concatenated and minified "`default.scss`" (1 line) and not refers to the real `.scss` file with the good line.

Is it a lack of Brunch, a bad config in my `brunch-config.coffee`, a bad use in my `scss` method?

My configuration :

```
- Brunch 1.8.5
- sass-brunch 1.9.1

SCSS Files tree: scss/default.scss (with @import of other sass files)
scss/_toto.scss + scss/_tata.scss + scss/_titi.scss …
```

Comment: I would suggest to disable source maps for now. We'll fix this.

Comment: OK, thank you @PaulMiller. It will be fixed in brunch or sass-brunch ? I’ve seen on [link]https://www.npmjs.com/package/brunch that I haven’t the last version of `brunch` (2.1.3) neither the last version of `sass-brunch` (1.9.3). However that may be, I’am updating…

Comment: Could you please report the issue to sass-brunch issue tracker? https://github.com/brunch/sass-brunch

Comment: OK, updating doesn’t change anything. I’ve just created an issue on your github.